# C# ArrayList.Add adding by Ref?

Tags: c#, inheritance, arraylist

I have a base 'Vehicle' class:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    private string company;
    private string model;

    private static int ID = 0;

    public Vehicle(string company, string model)
    {
        this.company = company;
        this.model = model;
        ID++;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
            return "\n\nVehicle Information: \n\t" +
                    "ID: "+ID+"\n\t"+
                    "Car: " + company + "\n\t" +
                    "Model: " + model + "\n\t";
    }
}
```

Now I have an inherited class 'Ford', inherited from Vehicle:

```
public class Ford : Vehicle
{
    public Ford(string company, string model) : 
                               base(company, model)
    {

    }        
}
```

I also have another inherited class 'Honda', inherited from Vehicle:

```
public class Honda: Vehicle
{
    public Honda(string company, string model) : 
                               base(company, model)
    {

    }        
}
```

Now in my Main method, I call the derived classes Ford and Honda, and add them to an ArrayList:

```
class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ArrayList vehicleList = new ArrayList();

        Ford firstVehicle = new Ford("Ford", "Fusion");
        vehicleList.Add(firstVehicle);


        vehicleList.Add(new Honda("Honda", "Civic"));


        foreach (Vehicle x in vehicleList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that, when I run it, I get the following output:

```
Vehicle Information:
    ID:2
    Car:Ford
    Model:Fusion
Vehicle Information:
    ID:2
    Car:Honda
    Model:Civic
```

As you can see, both the objects show the ID column '2' instead of 1 for the first and 2 for the second.
When I used the breakpoint to detect whats happening, I see that when the first object is processed, the arrayList shows ID=1 for the first object, but when the second object is processed and added to the arrayList, the ID value of the first object too is changed to 2 from 1.
I think this is because it is using 'add by reference'?? 
any suggestions what can I do to show ID:1 for the first and ID:2 for the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static int ID = 0;
private int instanceID;
public Vehicle(string company, string model)
{
    this.company = company;
    this.model = model;
    instanceID = ID++;
}
```

...and use `instanceID` in `ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

ID is static, therefore a singleton. There is one instance of it for the application (shared by all instances of Vehicle)

Start by changing this:

```
private static int ID = 0;
```

To this:

```
private static intCounter = 0;
private int ID = 0;
```

Then where your ID is being set replace:

```
ID++;
```

...with...

```
intCounter++;
ID = intCounter;
```

Comment: so what's my alternative ?

Comment: @RajivGanti, don't use static `ID`...why you need a static id in this case? care to explain?

Comment: @davidshen84 I think he's using it to generate unique ID's.

Comment: When I don't use 'static' and like I say:
private int ID = 0;
then in the output, I get:
ID:1 for both objects

Comment: @RajivGanti try the solution I suggested, but also it is a good idea to understand how static fields work. There is one instance for your application, not per class instance, so calling `Honda.ID` and `Ford.ID` will give the same value.